# Why does my AWK-Script wait for me to press a key?

Tags: awk

I started learning AWK today and I wrote a script that calculates powers of two. When I start it though, it waits for me to press enter and when it's done printing the powers of two, it doesn't print the word "End", although it's defined in the End section.

Here's my code:

```
BEGIN{
    print "Power of two"
    x=0
}
{
while(res<=1000){
    res = 2^x
    print 2 "^" x "=" res
    x++
}
}
END{
    print "End"
}
```

Comment: Because I believe you are not passing any Input_file to `awk` program?

Comment: I open the script by typing "gawk -f poweroftwo.awk"

Comment: ok, I just saw your script properly, you are not trying to operate on input data, but want a standalone awk script.. put entire the code in `BEGIN` or `END` or both, but you cannot have something in between.. that would tell awk to look for input data.. also, I think gawk version 5+ will not allow this kind of use

Comment: @Sundeep - she should put it in BEGIN, not END (the script would just hang). idk what you mean by `I think gawk version 5+ will not allow this kind of use` but if it's that gawk won't allow a BEGIN-only script - yes it will.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for clarification, I've misunderstood a few things.. also, I don't recall exactly, but perhaps I misread about `gawk -e 'BEGIN {' -e 'print "hello" }'` no longer allowed from https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2019-04/msg00002.html (which gives error for me anyway on version 4.1.3)

Comment: @Sundeep yeah there's something about that `-e` functionality that lets you inter-leave command line (`-e`) and file-based (`-f`) scripts that's changed recently. Now I remember - it's that each snippet has to be syntactically correct stand-alone so you can still write `-e 'BEGIN{print "foo"}' -e 'END{print "bar"}'` but you can no longer write `-e 'BEGIN{print "foo"' -e '} END{print "bar"}'`. They had to make that change to implement [namespaces](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Namespaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told your script to expect input by providing code between BEGIN and END (`{while ... }}`) to process that input. That section doesn't start till you provide input by hitting enter and then it won't end until you end the input by typing control-D at which point THEN your END section will be executed.

It sounds like this is what you intended to write instead:

```
BEGIN{
    print "Power of two"
    x=0

    while(res<=1000){
        res = 2^x
        print 2 "^" x "=" res
        x++
    }

    print "End"
}
```

or if you really want to have an END section for some reason:

```
BEGIN{
    print "Power of two"
    x=0

    while(res<=1000){
        res = 2^x
        print 2 "^" x "=" res
        x++
    }

    exit
}
END{
    print "End"
}
```

Comment: Looks good, very thorough, I had already upvoted the previous incarnation or I'd do it again now.

Answer (score 2):

You `awk` has in middle section that need some input (as @Sundeep writes)

Try this

```
echo "50" | awk '
BEGIN{
    print "Power of two"
    x=0
}
{
while(res<=$1){
    res = 2^x
    print 2 "^" x "=" res
    x++
}
}
END{
    print "End"
}'
Power of two
2^0=1
2^1=2
2^2=4
2^3=8
2^4=16
2^5=32
2^6=64
End
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, just wanted to clarify: so, if in an AWK program, a middle section is present, that is, a section between `BEGIN{}` and `END{}`, then it always expects some input (user, or pipe, or whatever), right? And if I don't want to provide such input, then I must only place my code in `BEGIN{}` and `END{}` sections, is this right?

Comment: @AS From what I have seen, yes.  Middle block needs input of some form.  BEGIN and END block are handled before and after input code are handled.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your program performs further actions upon keypress is that it is awaiting input. Input generally comes from files or output from another command when using a pipe. However, from time to time, awk can await input from `/dev/stdin`. This is the case when you call your program without any files as argument (See [[1]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) section *Extended description: Overall Program Structure*), or use <hyphen> as an argument (See [[1]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) section *Operands*).

```
$ awk -f source.awk                 # input from /dev/stdin via keyboard 
$ awk -f source.awk [file] -        # input from /dev/stdin via [file and] keyboard
$ cmd | awk -f source.awk           # input from /dev/stdin via pipe
$ cmd | awk -f source.awk [file] -  # input from /dev/stdin via [file and] pipe
```

Be aware that the above cases **might** need input from `/dev/stdin`. The need for input depends on the program structure of awk. So we can ask ourselves now the following question:

> When does awk require input from a file, command, keyboard or any other possible form of input?

An awk program is composed of pairs of the form:

```
pattern { action }
```

where `pattern` is generally a logical condition to determine whether or not `action` should be executed. Posix awk recognizes two special patterns, `BEGIN` and `END`. Gnu awk has other special patterns such as `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` but for this answer, we can classify them as a regular pattern. We can now make the following statements (See [[1]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) subsection *Special patterns*):

- A regular pattern **always** requires input.
- The special pattern `BEGIN` **does not** require input (except when it contains a `getline`)
- The special pattern `END` **always** requires input to be read before it is executed

From this we can say:

> *An awk program **does not require input** if*
>
> - *it only consists of `BEGIN` patterns which do not call `getline`.*
> - *or, a `BEGIN` pattern calls the `exit` routine* before any `getline` could be called.
>
> *in any other case, awk will require input!*

The last statement comes from the rules bound to the `exit` statement. The `exit` statement shall invoke all `END` actions in the order in which they occur in the program source and then terminate the program **without reading further input**.  (See [[1]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) subsection *Actions*)

Based on the above, we can now answer the OP's question:

> Why does my AWK-Script wait for me to press a key?

Since the OP's program roughly looks like:

```
 BEGIN { something without exit }
 pattern { something else }
 END { something final }
```

it will require input. Furthermore, the OP calls it as

```
$ awk -f file.awk
```

which implies that the input comes from `/dev/stdin`, or in this case, the keyboard. Therefore awk will wait to execute the regular action-pattern pair until it received a record (here a line) from the keyboard. I.e. press some keys followed by an <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Every time such a line has been sent, awk will process all regular patterns. The `END` pattern will only be executed when the input is finished. You can inform awk that the input via the keyboard is finished by sending an end-of-file (EOF) via keyboard. This is done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

A clean rewrite of the code can be found in the answer of [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56954054/8344060). A quick workaround in the answer of [Jotne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56951152/8344060).

[[1]: Posix standard, utility section, awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)